# How to test that a React component returning an empty fragment renders

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, vitest

Given two components such as:

(very contrived example)

```
const Parent = (props) => {
  const { someValue } = props;

  if (someValue === undefined) return null;

  return <Child someValue={someValue} />;
};

const Child = (props) => {
  const { someValue } = props;

  return (
    <>
      <Modal isOpen={someValue === "foobar"} />
      { /** ...Many more modals following the same pattern */ }
    </>
  );
};

// Modal implementation show here for understanding, but its a 3rd party
// component that I can't modify right now :(
const Modal = (props) => {
  const { isOpen } = props;

  if (!isOpen) return null;

  return <div>some content</div>;
}
```

How can I test that when `someValue` is not `undefined` that `Parent` properly renders `Child`? Because `Child` renders a fragment of things that themselves initially `render null`, the HTML of the successfully rendered `Parent` will be `""`, and I don't know of a way to differentiate that from `Parent` returning `null` itself.